# Setting loading call backs to WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

How can I define callback functions for `WKWebView` in swift?

For `UIWebView` I used:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ : UIWebView)
{}
```

And connecting it as delegate

My `WKWebView` is defined:

```
@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
var wkwebView: WKWebView?
...
self.wkwebView = WKWebView()
self.view = self.wkwebView
```

Comment: Do you agree with my answer? If so, vote it please! It's important to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in [`navigationDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKNavigationDelegate_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/WKNavigationDelegate/webView:didFinishNavigation:) of `WKWebView`.

```
// your ViewController should adopt WKNavigationDelegate protocol
self.wkwebView.navigationDelegate = self

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    // similar to webViewDidFinishLoad:
}
```